# When all tasks are done call a cleanup task in resque

Tags: ruby, resque

I have a web application witch relies on some workers to update its database. This workers will fetch some data over internet, update the corresponding entries and then remove the non updated entries.

When i was using threads it was fine because i had complete control of when the execution was done. I have to move it to resque because threads are great but it was to problematic to change scalability, so now, every old thread is now a worker.

It works great, but now i have this problem: I cant see when the workers are done and because of that i cant call a cleanup to remove the non updated entries.

my old code looks like this:

```
Entry.update_all(updated: false)
Docs.update_all(updated: false)
Stuff.update_all(updated: false)

# ...
# My code that uses find_or_create_by_my_custom_id
# Entry.find_or_create_by_tag(20)
# ...

Entry.delete_all(updated: false)
Docs.delete_all(updated: false)
Stuff.delete_all(updated: false)
```

And currently with resque i have this setup on my started worker (main worker called to start the whole thing):

```
Resque.enqueue(UpdateEntriesJob, params)
Resque.enqueue(UpdateDocsJob, params)
Resque.enqueue(UpdateStuffJob, params)
```

How can i get control of when this tasks where completed?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the `after_perform` hooks

in your worker class just add a after_performer class method

```
class UpdateEntriesJob
   ..... 
   ....
   def self.perform
     ... 
     ...
     ...
   end
   ....
   ....
   ....

   def self.after_perform
      ...
      [Write your code over]
      ...
   end

end
```

Hope this make sense

Comment: My only problem with this is some workers have 3 to 4 nested workers, meaning w1 calls w2, w2 calls w3 and w3 calls w4.

Comment: @NicosKaralis do have a worker which you know is the last in the list always then `after_perform` might work interesting approach though